# Can an LED Driver be mounted in a Ceiling Electrical box

Tags: led, lamp

Can an LED Driver be mounted in a Ceiling Electrical box? I want to install a custom LED Lamp fixture to replace the existing bedroom ceiling fixture.

Will it violate code to mount the LED Driver within the existing 2 gang electrical box?

Comment: The answer would be dependent on the listing for the driver and how much available space (wire & device fill). Can you provide more information on the driver.

Comment: 2 gang ceiling mounted?  Normally ceiling boxes are round...

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with a lamp having an internal DC power supply.

There is also nothing wrong with embedding a DC power supply in a junction box, provided there is a separator between mains AC voltage and DC.  For instance many furnace transformers are packaged *as* the lid to a standard junction box, or to fit in a standard knockout, with the AC power inside and the DC power outside.  I am unaware of any 12V LED power supplies in those packages, but I haven't really looked.

Comment: I don't believe you even need the divider -- Art. 411 doesn't call for it, provided you wire the low-voltage side according to Chapter 3.  It's only needed if you are running Class 2 or telecom-type wiring, AFAICT...